# Migrating short vb6 code that uses WinHttp.WinHttpRequest to c# or vb.net

Tags: c#, vb.net, vb6, httpwebrequest

can someone please guide me how to convert that vb6 code to c# or visual basic.net. i have tried to to use the  `System.Net.WebRequest()` class but with no success (everything i treys throws another exception so i think that adding my c# code will not be helpful).

this code works fine (i tested it with the vba editor).

**clarification: I DONT EXPECT SOME TO DO MY JOB i just need to understand the equivilent methods of the first 11 rows in  `GetHTTPResponse()` function to `System.Net.WebRequest()` class medhods , it will be enough and i will be able to handle it alone from that point.**

thank you very much for your time and consideration.

```
Function ReadToken(s)
    Dim X()
    ReDim X(0)
    s = Replace(s, Chr(34), "")
    bRes = False
    Set RegExp = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    RegExp.IgnoreCase = True
    RegExp.Pattern = "token\:(.+?),type\:(.+?),expires_in\:(.+?)"

    bRes = RegExp.test(s)
    If bRes Then
        Set oMatches = RegExp.Execute(s)
        ReDim X(2)
        X(0) = oMatches(0).subMatches(0)
        X(1) = oMatches(0).subMatches(1)
        X(2) = oMatches(0).subMatches(2)
    End If
    ReadToken = X

End Function

Function GetHTTPResponse(ByVal Id As Long) As String
' On Error Resume Next
    Const username = "username"
    Const password = "password"
    sURL = "https://api.exoclick.com/v1/login"
    Set oXMLHTTP = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
    With oXMLHTTP
        .Open "Post", sURL, False
        .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
        params = "{""username"":" & Chr(34) & username & Chr(34) & ", ""password"":" & _
                Chr(34) & password & Chr(34) & "}"
        .send params
        If .Status = 200 Then
            Response = .ResponseText
            Token = ReadToken(Response)
            Authorization = "{""type"":" & Chr(34) & Token(1) & _
                            Chr(34) & ",""token"":" & Chr(34) & Token(0) & Chr(34) & "}"
            .abort
            sURL = "https://api.exoclick.com/v1/statistics/advertiser/date"
            params = "{""campaignid"":" & Id & "}"
            .Open "GET", sURL, False
            .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
            .setRequestHeader "Authorization", Authorization
            .send params
            GetHTTPResponse = .ResponseText
        End If
    End With
    Set oXMLHTTP = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: You mention VB6 in the title, but VBScript in the question. Which is it?

Comment: sorry, fixed that its vb6

Comment: VB6 is generally pasteable into VB.NET as long as you add brackets to parameters and add at top of file `Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices` and `Imports Microsoft.Win32`. EG `Response = .ResponseText` becomes `Response = .ResponseText()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to perform a web request in C# is using the [`HttpClient`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.118).aspx) , as long as you support .NET 4.5+. Here's a simple example:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
       { "username", username },
       { "password", password }
    };

    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);
    var response = await client.PostAsync(sURL, content);
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {    
        var response = await response.Content.ReadAsString();
        // then repeat for the next request
    }
}
```

[Here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client) is a good resource for learning about HttpClient.

Be sure to mark your GetHTTPResponse method with the `async` keyword.

Comment: thank you for the example i will use it, but what property or method get the params string and setRequestHeader?